# Вызов dispatch_sync в AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Почему при вызове

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Hello world");
    });   
    return YES;
}
```

приложение упадёт, а при `dispatch_async` нет?

Comment: Не понятно, если в методе только `return YES;`, то падает, а если ещё и `dispatch_async`, то не падает? С какой ошибкой падает?

Comment: Падает если указывать `dispatch_sync`.

Comment: ааа, блин, не заметил что написано разное dispatch_sync/dispatch_async. Ну да, диспатч синк значит поставить в очередь главного потока этот блок и заморозить текущий пока блок не выполнится в главном потоке. А така как текущий - это и есть главный, то получается спать и не отдавать никому управления до тех пор пока не выполнится то, чему как раз управление мы и не отдаём

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что dispatch_sync ставит функцию в очередь на выполнение, и блокирует текущий поток пока функция не выполнится и не вернет значение. Таким образом, если делать dispatch_sync на текущий поток вы получите deadlock - текущая функция ждет ответа от функции, которая не может запуститься пока текущая функция не выполнилась.

Из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452870-dispatch_sync) apple:

> Submits a block to a dispatch queue for synchronous execution. Unlike dispatch_async, this function does not return until the block has finished. Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock.